# Interfacing AR0237 to CYUSB3014

Tags: imageprocessing, image-sensor

I'm currently creating a RGB+IR webcam application using the CYUSB3014 from Infineon with the AR0237 from OnSemi. After a bit of fiddling around with the help of the AN75779 from Infineon and the image sensor documentation from OnSemi, I was able to get some kind of image, however the image is only green and I haven't been able to give it proper colors in any way... This happened due to the output format being YUV, however even with RGB the image still only uses one color.

The sensor output is RAW12 and the CYUSB3014 has been configured to consider two bytes per pixel in order to properly build the image. I have followed the following [topic](https://community.infineon.com/t5/USB-superspeed-peripherals/FX3-12-bit-image-sensor-issue/m-p/338348) from Infineon, implemented the code in a OpenCV application and even directly spoke with the OP of that topic in order to get better results, however the best I could get was the following image:

[image: Orange and black Camera Output]

While this is the true expected image:

[image: Full color true image]

Hope you can give me some help regarding this problem and hope everything is clear enough.

Best regards,

RSar

Comment: Take pictures of red, blue and green test patterns, save the raw values and then check what you're converting them to.  Since your image seems to be rendering red and blue as solid black you're probably not handling the debayering correctly.

Comment: @user1850479 Thank you for the tip, do you have a tool suggestion for checking the value of the pixels on the raw file? I'm sorry if it is a simple thing, I'm quite new with image processing.

Comment: I think the last time I was troubleshooting this I used VLC to save the files as bitmaps and then loaded them in paint.net or irfanview to see the pixel values.

Comment: @user1850479 Sorry for the late reply. Well, I used fswebcam to acquire a RAW image and used a multicolor test pattern to see how it was presented, using the site https://rawpixels.net/ to check the pixel color values for each of the bars (I couldnt figure out how to do it with irfanview). The colors really aren't being captured correctly for some reason... I even used a test pattern from the camera, but the result was the same, none of the colors were correctly shown.
With a RAW, the debayering shouldn't be a problem yet right?